# Adding list box to specific column when cell value changed

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a datagridview that shows user data. I need to show the User Name List in a list box that attached to the user name column. When I type a name or a part of a name the list box should show the data referencing to the typed text.

I am using a array list to get the data from the table.
What I need to know is how can i display those data when i enter a value to the specific cell in data grid view
Please Help

This is my method to get the user name list

```
public ArrayList GetEmpNameLike(string empName)
    {
        SqlConnection myConnection;
        myConnection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DB-IT-USER;Initial Catalog=TRIOConstructionsInventory;User ID=sa;Password=dbit");
        myConnection.Open();

        ArrayList mtnList = new ArrayList();

        string sqlQuery = "select emp_userName from dbo.user_table WHERE emp_userName LIKE @empName";

        SqlCommand queryCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, myConnection);

        queryCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@empName", "%" + empName + "%");

        try
        {
            SqlDataReader reader = queryCommand.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                mtnList.Add(reader.GetString(0));
            }

            reader.Close();

            return mtnList;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message.ToString());
            return mtnList;
        }
    }
```

Here is my form
[image: When I type in the user name cell it should show a list box and show relevant data]

Comment: Show the code what you have tried so far

Comment: No code in question won't give you any useful answers !

Comment: Show the code and the image of your gridview

Comment: Thanks for the assist. I added the code that i done. please give me an idea to do this.